# Finding the solutions of the inequality $\|xb-a\|<1$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and consider bounded operators $a$ and $b$ on $H$.

For given operators $a$ and $b$, I am looking a way to get all solutions (bdd operators $x$) of the inequality   $\|xb-a\|<1$ in termes of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: This question would seem more sensible if you had certain restrictions on the norm of $a$ and the norm of $b$. Otherwise, if $\Vert a\Vert <1$ then I always get trivial solutions for any $b$, by taking $\Vert x\Vert$ to be very very small

Comment: Unfortunately, no restriction is permitted.

Comment: Well, then I don't think you can do anything, unless you start to consider possible cases. As I said above, if $a$ has small norm then any $x$ which has sufficiently small norm will work, and none of the intuition from the "solve $xb=a$" problem will be valid